# Jquery Countdowntimer shows same timer for multiple spans in error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with games detail. and I want to add a countdowntimer for every game.

I'm using the [jquery-countdownTimer](http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/) plugin

My Html:

```
<span class="given_date" data-gamestart="2016/3/11 15:30"></span>
<span class="given_date" data-gamestart="2016/3/13 18:00"></span>
<span class="given_date" data-gamestart="2016/3/15 17:45"></span>
<span class="given_date" data-gamestart="2016/3/22 19:45"></span>
```

and i user a this plugin to make the count down.

My js:

```
$('.given_date').countdowntimer({
            dateAndTime : "2016/3/10 17:05"
});
```

#### [A jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/geutsqko/)

My issue is, even though I provide a different time for each span, all of the timers show the same value and countdown in sync

Why does each span not show it's own timer based on my provided values?

Comment: You should link to or at least mention which plugin you are using, it'll help us help you  ;)

Comment: @DelightedD0D you don't need the plugin because the plugin work fine. my problem is how to pass the date of every span to the javascript function  to make the countdown

Comment: That is just not true. The plugin may already have functionality to handle this type of thing. Knowing what you're using helps us avoid an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), besides, what harm could mentioning it do?

Comment: @DelightedD0D this is the link of the plugin [link](http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your elements do not have `ids`.

This plugin uses the below code to set the timers then display their values. Note the `window['regexpMatchFormat_' + $this.attr('id')]`. This uses the id of each element to create a unique global variable to keep track of the timers. If your elements have no ids, you end up repeatedly overwriting your first timer

```
//Code for starting the timers.
        if (options.regexpMatchFormat != undefined && options.regexpReplaceWith != undefined && options.timeSeparator == undefined) {
            window['regexpMatchFormat_' + $this.attr('id')] = options.regexpMatchFormat;
            window['regexpReplaceWith_' + $this.attr('id')] = options.regexpReplaceWith;
        }



//Function for displaying the timer.
function html($this, content) {
    var processedContent = content;
    if (typeof window['regexpMatchFormat_' + $this.attr('id')] !== 'undefined' &&
            typeof window['regexpReplaceWith_' + $this.attr('id')] !== 'undefined') {
        var regexp = new RegExp(window['regexpMatchFormat_' + $this.attr('id')]);
        processedContent = content.replace(regexp,
                window['regexpReplaceWith_' + $this.attr('id')]);
    }
    $this.html(processedContent);
}
```

#### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/unzjakt0/45/)

This is why you should always link to the plugin you are using ;)

Comment: thanks man for your help,  i accept it as answer, one more question please. how can i convert a given GMT time to a user local time than use it in the plugin. for exemple this is GMT time "2016/03/13 18:00" and i enter from USA i want to convert that time to USA time then use it in the plugin,

Comment: @ler I would use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) for that, it makes it pretty trivial, [see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/wwbkvdr4/4/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to loop through the `span`s with jQuery's `.each()` and set up the countdowntimer within that loop. Something like this:

```
$('.given_date').each(function() {
    $(this).countdowntimer({
        dateAndTime : this.getAttribute("data-gamestart")
    });
});
```